# Is there a relationship between matrix rotation and the matrix form of complex numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, rotations

I was going through some basic work over matrices and their different uses. I came across the matrix form of complex numbers shown as such
\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\-b&a\end{bmatrix}

The next thing i looked at was the matrix rotation and found this Rotation Matrix
\begin{bmatrix}cos(\theta)&-sin(\theta)\\sin(\theta)&cos(\theta)\end{bmatrix}

What is the relationship(if any) between these two different Matrices.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions rather than posting images. Images can't be browsed, and are not accessible to those using screen readers. If you need help formatting math on this site, [here's](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) a tutorial To begin with, surround all math expressions (including numbers,) with `$` signs. Use ^ for exponents and _ for subscripts. `$x_1^{2/3}$` shows up as $x_1^{2/3}$.

Comment: Do you know the polar form for complex numbers?  $x+iy=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$

Comment: The matrix form of a complex number $a+bi$ is actually $$\begin{bmatrix}a &- b \\ b&a\end{bmatrix} \, .$$

Comment: @Joe Both are used, neither is necessarily more “correct”.

Comment: @BenGrossmann: My mistake. But I'm not sure I follow why the other way of writing the matrix makes sense. Here, the linear transformation being represented is multiplication by a complex number. Shouldn't the left column of the matrix denote what happens to the $\hat{i}$ vector (the number $1$), and the right column denote what happens to the $\hat{j}$ vector (the number $i$)?

Comment: If I plug in the values for a and b based on their polar form into the matrix form of complex number shown by @Joe than it results in the rotation matrix:

a=  cos(theta) 
b= sin(theta) 

\begin{bmatrix}a&-b\\b&a\end{bmatrix}
substituting the values of A and B
\begin{bmatrix}cos(\theta)&-sin(\theta)\\sin(\theta)&cos(\theta)\end{bmatrix}

Comment: You can transform the first kind of matrix   to the second one by multiplying 
$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\-b&a\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: @Joe That is a valid way to represent the complex numbers, but not the only way. For instance, we can take $\hat i$ to denote $i$ rather than $1$, or we can think of matrices as acting on row-vectors of coordinates rather than column-vectors.